# How to get the unique value from a cell which repeats multiple times in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find, vba

Hi All i have a data of around 50000 candidates and one of the column contains the subject like below .

[image: Column A for Example]
I want a formula in Column B to get the Unique Value from column A.
If all the values in `","` are same then i need the Single value else all the cell Data.(There may be multiple comma separated entries)

I tried `find` formula but is not working.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So the entries in column A always consist of precisely 3 comma-separated entries? If not, suggest you edit your example so as to be more realistic.

Comment: @XORLX  - i have edited my Question and there are more than 3 comma-separated entries as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work for any number of comma-separated entries:

`=IF(REPT(LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2&",")),1+LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","")))=A2&",",LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2)-1),A2)`

Regards

Comment: Thank you for adding REPT() to my library of functions... +1

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor You're welcome! A useful little function at times.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a mess but this will work:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID($A2,1,SEARCH(",",$A2,1)-1),$A2,LEN(MID($A2,1,SEARCH(",",$A2,1)-1)))),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID($A2,1,SEARCH(",",$A2,1)-1),$A2,LEN(MID($A2,1,SEARCH(",",$A2,1)-1))*2)),MID($A2,1,SEARCH(",",$A2,1)-1),$A2),$A2)`

If search finds the first word again past the length of it it checks again past double it's length. If that's a match it returns just that word and otherwise returns the entire cell.

I will keep trying to find a more elegant solution but for now, this'll do. Well providing you are always searching on an index of 3. If you aren't I can still do it but would like to use helper columns (or have a crack at VBA which is easily up to the task, I wan't to see effort first though as I won't code for free as a rule of thumb)